# Can't we add data into ArrayList without add() method in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, arraylist

```
int[] x = new int[5];
x[0] = 1;
x[1] = 2;
x[2] = 3;
x[3] = 4;
x[4] = 5;

System.Collections.ArrayList y = new System.Collections.ArrayList(5);
y.Add(1);
y[2] = 2;
```

The above gives a run time exception `"Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection."`

Why is this so ? Can't we add data into ArrayList using index same as int[] Array? Please provide me with some pointers to understand the reason behind this implementation.

Comment: @All: I am not looking for best practices over here. The above code is written just to understand the way C# compiles the code. My question is why can't the compiler give compile time error instead of run time ? An integer Array is allowed to add data via indexing where as it is not the same with ArrayList. Can you provide better explanation like any MSDN link / supporting argument why Microsoft has done this ?

Comment: The compiler does not give compile time errors neither for arrays nor for lists. How can the compiler know what the size of the array is if it is created at runtime?

Answer (score 2):

Your `ArrayList` only has one entry in it, and so index `2` is out of range. [`ArrayList#Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.add%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) adds to the list. Your list has an initial *capacity* of `5` because you called the [`ArrayList(Int32)` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0bb9cb1.aspx), but you've only added *one* actual entry to it (which will be at index `0`).

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you seem to have misunderstood is what the `ArrayList` constructor does. `new ArrayList(5)` does *not* create an `ArrayList` with five elements, as opposed to `new int[5]`, which *does* create an array with five elements (all having the value zero). A newly-created `ArrayList` is always empty, so any attempt to use `[]` to set the value of any element will crash, because there are no elements. This is the same behavior as a regular array if you had created an array by saying `new int[0]` - any attempt to index into it would crash. The only way to get a five-element `ArrayList` is to either use the constructor that takes a (five-element) collection as a parameter (as @Stilgar and @Kelon showed), or by calling e.g. `Add(0)` five times. After having done this, you can access `x[0]`, `x[1]`, ..., `x[4]`.

What *does* `new ArrayList(n)` do, then? It creates an `ArrayList` of size zero, but where the internal array that is used to store the values is given the size *n*, so that we can add *n* elements before the internal array must be replaced by a bigger one (which takes a little bit of time, which is why you in high-performance scenarios might want to use this constructor if you know how big the list will eventually become).

Comment: To narrow down my query - why does C# compile y[2]=2 perfectly and give a run time error ? Why doesn't it warn programmer saying "Assignment is not allowed prior adding element" ? I just wanted to uderstand the prime reason behind this design, there could be a legitimate reason behind this.

Comment: @Karthik: Neither C#, C++, C, nor Java give compiler errors or warnings in such a situation. The reason is most likely that there are very few cases where you can actually predict with certainty that the lookup will fail, and the compiler writers didn't want to bother with those rare (and unrealistically simple) cases. In almost all cases where you (in production code) perform an array lookup, the array was _not_ initialized immediately before (rather, it was passed as a parameter or it is a class member) and the index is a variable. Hence, the compiler cannot know whether it will fail or not.

Answer (score 0):

`new ArrayList(5)` just allocates memory for 5 entries. That's all. You still have to add or insert to a list - it's not the same as an array.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use a collection rather than an array like a  `List<int>();`

As for why see this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2604h5s(v=vs.80).aspx

> Class library designers might need to
>   make difficult decisions about when to
>   use an array and when to return a
>   collection. Although these types have
>   similar usage models, they have
>   different performance characteristics.
>   In general, you should use a
>   collection when Add, Remove, or other
>   methods for manipulating the
>   collection are supported.
>
> For more information about using
>   collections, see Collections and Data
>   Structures.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays initializes the memory with default values. Lists have different semantics. They are supposed to manage their size dynamically. The capacity you've provided (5) is purely optimization based on the specific list implementation. Not every IList implementation would have the same internal representation. What if the implementation was a LinkedList? You need to think about the concept of the data structure List not about the particular implementation.

If you want to assign values there are plenty of ways to initialize a list. You can pass an array to the constructor or use the collection initializers from C# 3.0. And please use List instead of ArrayList.

```
//Collection initializer
List<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

//passing array as an argument to the constructor
int[] ints = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
List<int> list2 = new List<int>(ints);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
new ArrayList(new int[5]);
```

this initializes the ArrayList with 5 given default entries.

**But**

```
y.Add(1); // would add a 6t entry
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the capacity when creating the `ArrayList`, but this is only so that the object can allocate space internally, the initial size of the list is still zero.

The difference between an `ArrayList` and an array is that the size of the list is dynamic. You can add and remove items, which is not possible with an array. It makes sense for a dynamically sized collection to start with the size zero, instead of filling it with zero-values.

Note: The `ArrayList` class is practically obsolete; you should use the generic `List<T>` class instead, which performs better and is easier to use, especially for value types like `int`.